# How to use templated iterators when value type of iterator is not know for a generalised STL Container?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I want to write *templated* function that

- accepts 2 iterators
- prints the content stored in container using *copy (defined in *algorithm* standard header).

Here is the piece of code I have written but produces compilation error

```
template <template<typename, typename> class Container, 
            typename Value, 
            typename Allocator = std::allocator<Value> >
void printContainer(Container<Value, Allocator>::iterator itBegin,
                    Container<Value, Allocator>::iterator itEnd)
{
        copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator<Value>(cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
}
```

Error produced are :

```
  error 1: variable or field ‘printContainer’ declared void
  void printContainer(Container<Value, Allocator>::iterator itBegin,
                                                   ^
  error 2: expected ‘)’ before ‘itBegin’
  void printContainer(Container<Value, Allocator>::iterator itBegin,
                                                            ^
  error 3: expected ‘)’ before ‘itEnd’
       Container<Value, Allocator>::iterator itEnd)
                                             ^
 p00441.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 p00441.cpp:10:39: error: ‘printContainer’ was not declared in this scope
   printContainer(inp.begin(), inp.end());
```

Another snippet I wrote is

```
template<typename InputIterator>
void printContainer(InputIterator itBegin, InputIterator itEnd){
        //Trial 1
        copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator< iterator_traits<ForwardIterator1>::value_type>(cout, " "));

        //Trial 2
        copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator<value_type(itBegin)*>(cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
}
```

Error produced are :

```
error 1: ‘ForwardIterator1’ was not declared in this scope
   copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator< iterator_traits<ForwardIterator1>::value_type>(cout, " "));
                                                          ^
error 2: template argument 1 is invalid
   copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator< iterator_traits<ForwardIterator1>::value_type>(cout, " "));
                                                                          ^
error 3: template argument 1 is invalid
   copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator< iterator_traits<ForwardIterator1>::value_type>(cout, " "));
                                                                                       ^
error 3: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _CharT, class _Traits> class std::ostream_iterator’
   copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator<value_type(itBegin)*>(cout, " "));
                                                             ^
error 4:   expected a type, got ‘(value_type(itBegin) * <expression error>)’
```

Please elaborate what errors mean and their cause of occurrence. Also suggest how to achieve the desired goal.

I will be grateful if you could suggest some sources for a novice to understand iterators.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear why the `Container` or `Allocator` are even part of your template type parameters. Wouldn't just an `Iterator` work ? You can still decipher it's value type via `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Container is used so that I can just pass a reference to the generalised container and use container.size() to display all elements. However iterators are more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you can simply use the iterator as the template type and use `iterator::value_type`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename Iterator>
void printContainer(Iterator itBegin,
                    Iterator itEnd)
{
        copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator<typename Iterator::value_type>(cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    list<int>   l{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    printContainer(begin(v), end(v));
    printContainer(begin(l), end(l));

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/DhUQ1t

Using `iterator_traits` also works and is a better solution since it will also work for pointers (that naturally do not have the `value_type` member; thanks to Jarod42 for pointing this out):

```
template <typename Iterator>
void printContainer(Iterator itBegin,
                    Iterator itEnd)
{
        copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator<typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>(cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/8N0ook

Starting with C++14, you can also use `decltype` and `decay_t`:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void printContainer(Iterator itBegin,
                    Iterator itEnd)
{
        copy(itBegin, itEnd, ostream_iterator<decay_t<decltype(*itBegin)>>(cout, " "));
        cout << endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/7MBsiL

---

Regarding your other tries, there's no `ForwardIterator1` defined in your function and `value_type` is a `typedef`, not a function.

Comment: `iterator_traits` is better than `Iterator::value_type` as the former works with regular pointers.

Comment: `decay_t` might be used in addition to `decltype` to have equivalent code.

Comment: @Jarod42: thanks for pointing those things out. I've updated the first one, but I'm not sure about the second one: what would be the use for `decay`?

Comment: @rainer `decltype(*itBegin)` will return (`const`-qualified) reference to `value_type`, or `(const) value_type&` - If you only want `value_type`, you need to remove the reference and the (possible) `const`-qualification, which is what [`std::decay_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) does.

Comment: @rainer Thank u and all other people who helped me solve this problem. Now I can focus more on problem than just printing Container :)

Comment: Any comments on why we have to use _typename_ with `Iterator::value_type` and `iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`. Its just the syntax or something subtle. _Iterator_ itself refers to that its a  templated type as in function parameters.

Comment: This is basically just the syntax. Since `Iterator` is a template, it might be anything, including `struct Something { static int const value_type = 1234; };`; ie., the compiler cannot know that what you're referring to is actually a type. That's what you're telling it using `typename`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name for details.